# Correct way to extract values from Django Query

Tags: python, django

How do you set the results of a Django query to equal a new set of variables?
for example, when I run this query on my Django shell:

```
getDefaults = defaultParams.objects.filter(isDefault = True, device = 41)
```

then run:

```
for val in getDefaults.values():
    print(val)
```

It returns:

```
{'id': 2, 'device_id': 41, 'customerTag': 'ABCD001', 'isDefault': True}
```

I would like to use the values in this dictionary to save a new record into my database, but can't seem to extract the values from the dictionary?
I thought it would be something like:

```
device_id = getDefaults.device_id
NewCustomerTag = getDefaults.customerTag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values()` explicitly returns a list of dictionaries, so you would need to use dictionary syntax: `val['device_id']`.

But in your case there is no reason to do that. Skip the `values` call altogether, and you will get an instance of defaultParams on which you can use normal attribute lookups:

```
for val in getDefaults:
    print(val.device_id)
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman. How would I access the values in the query without a for loop? For example, after I declare getDefaults = defaultParams.objects.filter(isDefault = True, device = 41), why does't getDefaults.device_id return 41?

Comment: `filter()` returns a queryset, ie a list of multiple items. If you know your query will return one item, use `.get()` instead.

Comment: .get() was what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can not do **getDefaults.device_id** since **defaultParams.objects.filter** return a list of matched objects.

If you are sure you get a single match do as follows.

```
device_id = getDefaults[0].device_id
NewCustomerTag = getDefaults[0].customerTag
```

or

you can iterate through the list and use the dict data.

```
for val in getDefaults:
    device_id = val.device_id
    NewCustomerTag = val.customerTag
```

If you want to save the retrieved object info as new object I would suggest the following approach.

```
getDefaults = defaultParams.objects.filter(isDefault = True, device = 41)

getDefaults[0].pk = None

getDefaults[0].save()
```